# How to clip an image to remove its padding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm displaing thumbnail image from YouTube. These images has black rectangles at the top and bottom.

I want to display image without that rectangles. How I can set vertical "padding" to remove that black rectangles.

```
Image(
       painter = rememberImagePainter("https://img.youtube.com/vi/RS6By_pE7uo/0.jpg"),
       modifier = Modifier
            .width(itemWidth)
            .height(photoImageHeight)
       contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
 )
```

Comment: I can't think of any way to remove those rectangles from the image. I guess you can wrap your `Image` in a `Box` along with two more boxes (one for top, one for bottom) with some fixed small height and background set to your screen background. The boxes will hide the top and bottom of your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the image inside a Box whose width is the same as the image but whose height is reduced by the amount of height used by the black bars above and below the image. Then use `cropToBounds`:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val w = 480f / LocalDensity.current.density * 2.7f
            val h = 360 / LocalDensity.current.density * 2.7f

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredWidth(w.dp)
                    .requiredHeight(h.dp - 70.dp)
                    .clip(shape= RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .requiredWidth(w.dp)
                        .requiredHeight(h.dp),
                    painter = rememberImagePainter(
                        data = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/RS6By_pE7uo/0.jpg",
                    ),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code. It shows rounded corners on all corners. I replaced clipToBounds with just clip.